# adding panel within panel dynamically with autoadjust

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I want to add panels within a panel dynamically, since i dont know upfront the numbers of panels which i need to add.

This works fine if i do

```
panel.insert(<panel to be added>);
```

The parent panel is configured with the hbox layout.

But if the overall width of added panels goes beyond the parent panel width then there is a overflow and a horizontal scrollbar appears.

Rather what i am looking is it should add the panels to the next line automatically if it reaches the parent panels width.

Any solution to the above problem, might be i need to use some other layout here but not sure on that.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried to set inner panel width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parent panel layout should be Table with number of columns specified.
See the following code for parent panel

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    itemId: 'productListPanel',
    height: 500,
    width: 600,
    layout: {
        type: 'table',
        columns: 3
    },
    autoScroll: true
}
```

now i can add any number of child panels to it, see the following code.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                width: 190,
                height: 150,
                padding: 10,                  
                cls: 'myPanel',
                title: "Child Panle"+i
                });
                parentPanel.insert(panel);
             }
```

This solved my problem, hope it helps somebody.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have one idea but you should try in your code then let me know the result. Basically, set layout type to `auto`.

```
var resultsPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Results',
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    id: 'panel_one',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    layout: {
        type: 'auto',       // Arrange child items vertically
        align: 'stretch',    // Each takes up full width
        padding: 5
    }
});

var opanel = Ext.getCmp('panel_one');
console.log(opanel);
opanel.add([
    {
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Inner Panel',
        width: Ext.getCmp('panel_one').getWidth(),
        height: 100
    }
]);

opanel.add([
    {
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Inner Panel',
        width: Ext.getCmp('panel_one').getWidth()
        height: 100
    }
]);
```

Comment: it adds the panels in vertical fashion,  i dont want that... i changed the parent panel layout to Table and it is solved.